# Setting up $(".mydiv").myFunction();

Tags: jquery, plugins

This may be a ridiculously obvious question, so please forgive me.

I've seen several jQuery plugins that allow you do things like `$(".fb").fancybox();` to enable that plugins functionality for that class. How can I do that for my own jQuery stuff? For example, I've written a gallery system that I like quite a bit, and I'd like to be able to set up `$(".myClass").revGallery();`, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/

Comment: Read this http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$.fn.revGallery= function() {   
 //whatever it does
}; 

//then you can use it as described
$( "a" ).revGallery();
```